# javascript buttons how do i delete a class from all buttons when a certain value is selected?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, button, addeventlistener

I have a couple of buttons with one button that should disable all others. I wrote a code that selects buttons by adding a class and when clicked again deletes the class. It also pushed the value into an array. I want to make the no preference button in my code to delete a certain class from all buttons, except for the no preference button.

I already made it so it deletes everything in the array when it is clicked, but I just gotta delete the class from all buttons.

Code:

```js
    let div = document.getElementById('buttonDiv');

    let arr = [];

    div.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        let tgt = event.target;

        function SelectedClass() {
            if (tgt.classList.contains('Selected')) {
                tgt.classList.remove('Selected');
            } else {
                tgt.classList.add('Selected');
            }
        }

        if (tgt.classList.contains('buttons')) {
            if (arr.indexOf(tgt.value) === -1) {
                if (tgt.value === 'Ignore') {
                    if (tgt.classList.contains('Selected')) {
                        tgt.classList.remove('Selected');
                    } else {
                        tgt.classList.add('Selected');
                        arr = [];
                    }
                } else {
                    SelectedClass();
                    arr.push(tgt.value);
                }
            } else {
                arr.splice(arr.indexOf(tgt.value), 1);
                SelectedClass();
            }
        }
        console.log(arr);
    })
```

```css
    .buttondiv {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        height: 675px;
        margin-left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        margin-top: 50px;
    }

    .buttons {
        width: 275px;
        height: 50px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        ;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 3px;
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
    }

    .Selected {
        background-color: orangered;
        color: white;
        border: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="buttondiv" id="buttonDiv">
    <button value="btn1" class="buttons">1</button>
    <button value="btn2" class="buttons">2</button>
    <button value="btn3" class="buttons">3</button>
    <button value="btn4" class="buttons">4</button>
    <button value="Ignore" class="buttons">No Preference</button>
</div>
```

I tried doing it with a for loop and a queryselector, but that didn't work. Does anybody know a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly the code can be simplified. See example below where different actions are taken place based on weather you press the no preference button or an other button. For this I added a class to the no preference button so we can easily query on that.

```js
let div = document.getElementById('buttonDiv');

    let arr = [];

    div.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        let tgt = event.target;

        if (tgt.classList.contains('buttons')) {
          //when no preference is clicked remove all selected classes and empty the array
          if(tgt.value === 'Ignore') {
            event.currentTarget.querySelectorAll('.buttons').forEach((el) => {
              el.classList.remove('Selected');
              arr = [];
            });
          }
          //when other button is clicked removed the selected class from the no preference button and push the current value to the array
          else {
            event.currentTarget.querySelector('.buttons.ignore').classList.remove('Selected');
            arr.push(tgt.value);
          }
          //always add selected class to the current button.
          tgt.classList.add('Selected');
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
    })
```

```css
.buttondiv {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        height: 675px;
        margin-left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        margin-top: 50px;
    }

    .buttons {
        width: 275px;
        height: 50px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        ;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 3px;
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
    }

    .Selected {
        background-color: orangered;
        color: white;
        border: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="buttondiv" id="buttonDiv">
    <button value="btn1" class="buttons">1</button>
    <button value="btn2" class="buttons">2</button>
    <button value="btn3" class="buttons">3</button>
    <button value="btn4" class="buttons">4</button>
    <button value="Ignore" class="buttons ignore">No Preference</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! this code is a little easier in a bigger project of mine

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from my example i add a querySelectorAll to all button except for ignore button, when user click to "No Preference" `forEach` will disabled or enabled all.

```js
let div = document.getElementById('buttonDiv');

let arr = [];

div.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  let tgt = event.target;

  function SelectedClass() {
    if (tgt.classList.contains('Selected')) {
      tgt.classList.remove('Selected');
    } else {
      tgt.classList.add('Selected');
    }
  }

  if (tgt.classList.contains('buttons')) {
    if (arr.indexOf(tgt.value) === -1) {
      if (tgt.value === 'Ignore') {
        if (tgt.classList.contains('Selected')) {
          tgt.classList.remove('Selected');
          document.querySelectorAll('button:not(.ignore)').forEach(el => {
            el.disabled = false;
          });
        } else {
          tgt.classList.add('Selected');
          document.querySelectorAll('button:not(.ignore)').forEach(el => {
            if (el.classList.contains('Selected')) {
              el.classList.remove('Selected');
            }
            el.disabled = true;
          });
          arr = [];
        }
      } else {
        SelectedClass();
        arr.push(tgt.value);
      }
    } else {
      arr.splice(arr.indexOf(tgt.value), 1);
      SelectedClass();
    }
  }
  console.log(arr);
})
```

```css
.buttondiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 675px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.buttons {
  width: 275px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  ;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.Selected {
  background-color: orangered;
  color: white;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttondiv" id="buttonDiv">
  <button value="btn1" class="buttons">1</button>
  <button value="btn2" class="buttons">2</button>
  <button value="btn3" class="buttons">3</button>
  <button value="btn4" class="buttons">4</button>
  <button value="Ignore" class="buttons ignore">No Preference</button>
</div>
```

Reference:

- [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled)